# Modify specific helm toYaml output template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the following in my dep.yml `{{ toYaml .Values.volumes | indent 8 }}` which takes an array from `values.yml` of volumes and then loads it on the dep.yml file.

I want the following result on my dep.yml from the initial array

```
 volumes:
    - name: volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: {{ Release.Name }}-volume-claim
    - name: volume-a
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: {{ Release.Name }}-volume-a-claim
    - name: volume-b
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: {{ Release.Name }}-volume-b-claim
```

Adding the `{{ Release.Name }}` dynamically to the volume claim name for each element of the array.

Is there any way to achieve this modifying the `{{ toYaml .Values.volumes | indent 8 }}` directive?

Answer (score 16):

Helm includes [a `tpl` function](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#using-the-tpl-function) that expands template content in a string.  I would fit this into the pipeline after rendering the value to a string, but before indenting it; its parameters don't quite fit into the standard pipeline setup.

```
{{ tpl (toYaml .Values.volumes) . | indent 8 }}
```