# How do I process text through tpl before formatting it with toyaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

In [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651155/modify-specific-helm-toyaml-output-template) it seems like you should be able to render text with `toYaml` and then pass it to `tpl` but that isn't working for me.

Take the following:

```
#values.yaml
configMaps:
  test:
    data:
      config.yaml: |-
        aaaaaa: sdlkfjlskdfj
        bbbb: sdlkfjlskdfj
        ccccc: sdlkfjlskdfj
          ssdfs: slkdjflksdj
        cccc: sdlkfjlskdfj
          lskdjflksd: slkdjflksdj
          sdfs: slkdjflksdj
        AList: 
          - aaaa
          - bbbb
          - cccc

#In my chart
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mymap
data:
  {{ tpl (toYaml .Values.configMaps.test.data) . }}
```

This works until I actually add something to the text that needs to get rendered.

When I try to add a function to that text I get an error:

```
#values.yaml
configMaps:
  test:
    data:
      config.yaml: |-
        valueFromFunction: prefix-{{ include "myfunction" . }}-suffix
        aaaaaa: sdlkfjlskdfj
        bbbb: sdlkfjlskdfj
        ccccc: sdlkfjlskdfj
          ssdfs: slkdjflksdj
        cccc: sdlkfjlskdfj
          lskdjflksd: slkdjflksdj
          sdfs: slkdjflksdj
        AList: 
          - aaaa
          - bbbb
          - cccc
```

That's because by the time it gets to `tpl` the function looks something like this: `include \\\"myfunction\\\"\n`

I tried running it through `tpl` *first* but that gives me another error: `wrong type for value; expected string; got map[string]interface {}`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?  After fixing indents for `ssdfs`, `lskdjflksd`, and `sdfs`, I'm able to successfully template your setup (templating `.Values.configMaps.test.data` with an inner reference to a named template `myfunction`).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to write and escape strings in YAML.  It looks like `toYaml` is picking a double-quoted string, which doesn't work for this particular case.

For this particular setup, you probably know that `.Values.configMaps.test.data` has a specific structure: it is a string-keyed map with string values, and there is no further nesting.  If you take advantage of that knowledge, then you can invoke `tpl` on the string values directly, and there will not be an additional layer of YAML quoting.

You should be able to do something like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mymap
data:
{{- $k, $v := range .Values.configMaps.test.data }}
  {{ $k }}: |-
{{ tpl $v . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```